# What is the difference between "Mobile-first Responsive" and "Twitter Bootstrap" on Initializr?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, html5boilerplate, initializr

What is the difference between "Mobile-first Responsive" and "Twitter Bootstrap" on [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is mobile-first. Mobile first basically means you design for the mobile user in mind first, and then adapt as you increase window size. So there isn't a difference between "mobile-first" and Bootstrap. The difference is between Responsive and Bootstrap because Bootstrap is a framework and Responsive is more or less a "dumbed-down" version - less bloat if you don't need a bunch of elements.

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame they don't provide a short description don't you think? Any idea on where I should go to suggest them implementing this?

Comment: https://github.com/verekia/initializr-website/issues - the whole site is on Github :)